# Procedure esta executando apenas a primeira parte, porque?

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde, tenho duas tabelas, uma tabela `tb_addresses` com atributos

`idaddress int(11),
idperson int(11),
desaddres varchar(128), 
descomplement varchar(128)`

E existe uma chave primaria da tabela `tb_persons`, e uma tabela `tb_persons` com atributos `idperson`, `desperson`

criei uma procedure assim :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_addresses_save`(

pidaddress int(11), 
pidperson  int(11), 
pdesaddress VARCHAR(128), 
pdescomplement VARCHAR(32), 




)
BEGIN

    DECLARE vidperson INT(11);

    INSERT INTO tb_persons (desperson)
    VALUES('AAAA');

    SET vidperson = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO tb_addressses (idperson, desaddress, descomplement)
    VALUES(vidperson,'Meu endereco','Descomplement');

    SELECT * FROM tb_addresses a INNER JOIN tb_persons b USING(idperson) WHERE a.idaddress = LAST_INSERT_ID();

END
```

Porém , quando vou executar a procedure, apenas o primeiro `insert` é feito, no caso o de persons, o `insert` de address não ocorre, porque está ocorrendo apenas uma parte da procedure? 
Eu fui pesquisar mais apareceu isso:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Porém eu não entendo, se já existe um `idperson` setado na tabela `tb_address`, no caso o `last_insert_id()`, porque fica dando esse erro?

Comment: Sua lista de campos está sintaticamente errada já que você a inicia com uma `,`.

Comment: Não , ali foi pq eu copiei e colei aqui, mas nos testes aqui não tinha a virgula n, e msm assim dava error

Comment: Parece que o problema está aqui: LAST_INSERT_ID(); de onde você busca esse valor?